# How to implement drill down in Area chart amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to implement clickable area chart for each data item in the chart using amchart.js. But in the chart it does not show the clickable sign or chart cannot be clicked. I have tried different column chart, bar chart drill down in amchart library which can be implement using urlField attribute in the graph.
But when I use the same way for area chart it does not work.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: You show provide more information as to what is giving error, which error is being given, what is your code and what have you tried. You might as well find helpful guidelines on [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com.br/help/how-to-ask). Alternatively, I recommend Google Chart API. It's a great API to write charts in JS and it comes with clickable region out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Area char is basically a line graph with a fill. Line graph does not generate click events unless clicked on the bullet.

If your graph does not have bullets, no click events will take place.

To work around that, simply enable bullets. If you don't need them to be visible, set [`bulletAlpha: 0`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletAlpha). I.e.:

```
graphs: [{
  "fillAlphas": 0.5.
  "valueField": "value",
  "urlField": "url",
  "bullet": "round",
  "bulletAlpha": 0
}]
```